# what is the best clustering for 3d points?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, cluster-analysis, spatial

There are about 10 points in 3d space. The goal is to find the number of clusters and it's position. What is the best clustering method for it?
I have seen Complete_Linkage and DBSCAN clustering. Which one is more efficiently?

Comment: Did you try K-means? To find the (good) number of clusters, you may use Bayesian K-means:http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0352.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I do not have number of clusters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a space filling curve for example translate the co-ordinate to a binary and interleave it. Treat it as base-4 number. Then sort the numbers.

Comment: Is there any example for complete linkage with WEKA?

Answer (score 0):

With 10 points, **efficiency** is your least concern.

DBSCAN is meant for larger data. Hierarchical clustering is the way to go with such tiny data.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any example for complete linkage with WEKA?

Comment: Maybe. Have you checked the weka book?